# Invalid attempt to call IsDBNull when reader is closed

Tags: linq

I am trying to run query using Linq. Sometime query run successfully sometimes its giving me following error

"Invalid attempt to call IsDBNull when reader is closed"

I am not able to identify the root cause of this issue. If anyone knows about it please help me to solve this problem. 
Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
lstitems = lstAllItems.Join(db.Users, i => i.UserId, u => u.UserID, (i, u) => new {
    i, u
}).GroupJoin(db.UserProfile, u => u.u.UserID, up => up.UserID, (u, up) => new {
    u, up
}).SelectMany(sm => sm.up.DefaultIfEmpty(), (sm, up) => new {
    sm, up
})
    .AsEnumerable().Select(s => new ItemList {
    Title = s.sm.u.i.Title,
    UserId = s.sm.u.i.UserId,
    ItemId = s.sm.u.i.ItemId,
    RoomId = s.sm.u.i.RoomId,
    Description = s.sm.u.i.Description,
    OriginalImagePath = s.sm.u.i.OriginalImagePath,
    IdeaBookCount = db.IdeaBook.Where(o => o.UserId == s.sm.u.i.UserId && o.IsDeleted == false).Select(x => x.IdeaBookId).Count(),
    OwnerUserId = s.sm.u.u.UserID,
    ownerIdStatus = s.sm.u.u.IdStatus,
    OwnerName = s.sm.u.u.UserType == (int) UserType.RenovateProfessional ? s.sm.u.u.CompanyName : s.sm.u.u.FirstName + " " + s.sm.u.u.LastName,
    OwnerUserName = s.sm.u.u.UserName,
    OwnerImg = s.sm.u.u.UserType == (int) UserType.RenovateProfessional ? Utilities.ImagePathForProfileForCompany(s.up == null || s.up.profileImg == null ? "" : s.up.profileImg) : Utilities.ImagePathForProfileForUser(s.up == null || s.up.profileImg == null ? "" : s.up.profileImg),
    OwnerCoverPic = s.sm.u.u.UserType == (int) UserType.RenovateProfessional ? Utilities.ImagePathForCoverImageForCompany(s.up == null || s.up.CoverImg == null ? "" : s.up.CoverImg) : Utilities.ImagePathForCoverImageForUser(s.up == null || s.up.CoverImg == null ? "" : s.up.CoverImg),
    OwnerPlace = s.sm.u.u.location == null ? "" : s.sm.u.u.location,
    IsContractor = s.sm.u.u.UserType == (int) UserType.RenovateProfessional ? true : false,
    OwnerNameHref = BaseUrl + (s.sm.u.u.UserType == (int) UserType.RenovateProfessional ? "Pro/" : "User/") + s.sm.u.u.UserName,
    CommentCount = db.ItemCounts.Where(u => u.ItemId == s.sm.u.i.ItemId).Select(x => x.CommentsCount).FirstOrDefault(),
    LikeCount = db.ItemCounts.Where(u => u.ItemId == s.sm.u.i.ItemId).Select(x => x.LikesCount).FirstOrDefault()
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve it?

Comment: It's not clear where a reader is involved or where `IsDBNull` is called. This question needs debugging details.

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase the value of CommandTimeOut as shown below :-

```
database.CommandTimeout = int.MaxValue;
```

Comment: I am not getting "CommandTimeout" property with my dbcontext but still I put thiis connection timeout with connection string in web.config file but it didn't worked.

Comment: I am using code first approach and most of the places I am having same issue. I am not sure why its happening. As I am debugging code, sometime its get executed properly and sometimes throw this exception. If anybody has solution of this please share here.

Comment: Neel I put my code above. Please look in to this and suggest me some solution if possible.

Comment: have you used SqlDataReader  in ur application @VipinRathore?

Comment: No, I am using Linq query only.

Comment: i have just faced this problem.If you are sure that you have done every thing right then one of the possible reason  could be the problem in internet connection if you are connecting to a remote database and you just lost the connection in middle of this. NTM: interestingly i have to try 3 times to submit this comment due to my net problem

Answer (score -1):

The reason of this problem is reading a nullable column value.

Comment: Why? `IsDBNull` is only called to check if an `object` is `DbNull`. The question doesn't give sufficient details to answer it anyway.